# Accesing Python code (project) with two different machines

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

First of all I am relatively new in Python and maybe missing something about setting up a project in PyDev. I use PyDev with eclipse and windows OS.

I am trying to work on the same project with two different machines. Basically my code is situated in a shared folder on Dropbox. I would like to access the same project (not necessarily simultaneously) on both machines.

When I try to import the files in the project folder, PyDev on my second machine creates another file that is specific to it. Thus not the same file but a copy of the original project.

I am proficient in MATLAB and I expect, probably mistakenly, the same file instances to be read on both machines.

I feel the answer is quite simple but could bot bump into it after an hour of googling.

Thanks for your help in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are thinking of sharing code between multiple machines, you'd be better off using tools made specifically for that. They're called revision control system. You can read/try SVN and Git. You can probably get started with Github easily if you don't mind your code being public.

As for the project in Eclipse, there is a checkbox you can uncheck that moves the content of the project to your workspace, which is not what you want since you want to keep it in the Dropbox folder. I think it's called "Copy project into workspace".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know about GitHub but since my project is a single author one, did not want to invest into it. And I am doubtful whether this could solve my problem to be honest.

I will check copy project into workspace advice. thanks

Comment: @Sertac Github will probably not solve this particular problem but it's a better approach to use it instead of Dropbox for code. Apart from this, I think it's this checkbox you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of using GIT?  You can create the project on one machine and clone it on the other.  If you can't network the machines, sign up for github for bitbucket.  It really a huge jump from using drop box.  You can also use subversion from Unfuddled, which I don't recommend. You get one account for free with Unfuddled.

Comment: GitHub has a more beginner-friendly client.

Comment: @JesseTG And also a terrible client for Windows which OP is using. So it's really a matter of taste in the end.

Comment: @jadkik94 But he is using eclipse with has a GIT client and may have a better interface.  I can't speak to much to it but what little I used it, it wasn't to bad especially for a small project with no collaborators.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know about GitHub but since my project is a single author one, did not want to invest into it. And I am doubtful whether this could solve my problem to be honest

Comment: You can get a free GitHub account if you don't mind your project's source being public.  If you're a student, however, you can get five private repos for two years, for free!  (Go to github.com/edu)  And again, GitHub's client, though less powerful than raw Git, is stupidly easy to use.

Comment: Also, jadkik94, I would like to add that yes, GitHub's client isn't as powerful as others, but it's super easy to use, which is important when introducing people to version control.